# Rsync in crontab not execute

Tags: debian

I already made rsync with the ssh key, when I put it in crontab, the command is not executed

`#Full Backup at 1 AM`

`0 1 * * * rsync -avzhe "ssh -p 22" root@192.168.201.8:/backups/mysql/ /home/DB >> /var/log/cron.log`

please help me and thank you very much
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't guess. You must alone check each component individually:

1. whether cron runs anything else
2. Save the script in a file and call it in cron
3. whether your script works correctly in the shell and the target
   system allows you to log in as root
4. whether user cron has the same permissions to execute the script
5. whether cron user 'sees' the ssh key
6. other ...